# How can I apply my VBA code to a range of cells?

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, range

The purpose of my code acts upon the user input, which then automatically creates a hyperlink, based on what the user has input into the cell.

If the user types in `hello` into the cell, a hyperlink is created and links to `www.google.com/hello`.

Each cell will have a different input, so it is vital that my range extends from just `hello`, to other user inputs.

I have this working for one cell only, but when I try and span it out into multiple cells, I get a mis-match error, and I suspect that is due to me referencing cells wrong or something.

Here's my code:

```
Sub automaticHyperlink()

Dim link As String

link = "http://www.google.com/" & Range("F2")

Range("F2").Hyperlinks.Add Range("F2"), link

End Sub
```

When I change all range references from `F2` to `F2:F4`, I then get an error.

My question is, how do I properly apply this code to a multiple range of cells without producing an error?

Any questions, then please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suggest putting what the text you want to display, as its own String.  Then, simply loop through your range.

```
Sub automaticHyperlink()

Dim link As String, dispText As String
Dim cel As Range
Dim lastRow as Long

lastRow = Cells(rows.count,6).End(xlup).Row

For Each cel In Range("F2:F" & lastRow)
    dispText = cel.value
    link = "http://www.google.com/" & dispText
    cel.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=cel, Address:=link, TextToDisplay:=dispText
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Display text should be the users input. Each cell will have a different input, so having it referencing one cell will not work. I get a mis-match error when I try and make the range the whole of F column.

Comment: @juiceb0xk - See my edit.  Also, I don't suggest doing `Range("F:F")`, as that could take forever and possibly throw errors.  Instead, I suggest finding the last row, as I have in the edited code.

Comment: That's awesome, so much to learn with VBA, thank you so much.